# Why MongoDB can't store date correctly?

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine

In my form, I need to enter a date of purchase, I enter it in this format: DD/MM/YYYY (ie. 15/07/2019).

This field is a Mongo Date field.

But, when I enter this date : 01/02/2015, instead of : "2015-02-01T00:00:00.000+00:00", it saves "2015-01-31T23:00:00.000+00:00".

This is a problem because when I query and reorder the purchases by month, this purchase appears in January instead of February.

Maybe this is a Time zone problem but I think there is no way to change the default UTC Time zone in Mongo.

If so, I'm wondering what is the logic I should adopt in my controller?

**UPDATE**

I may have found a solution:

On my controller, before storing the date in the collection:

```
$string = '01/02/2015';
$datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat('j/m/Y', $string, new DateTimeZone('UTC'));

$datetime->setTime(00, 00, 00);
echo $datetime->format(DateTime::RFC3339_EXTENDED);

// Result: 2015-02-01T00:00:00.000+00:00
```

Then I store the result in the collection.

This is probably way too much, but is there a better solution?

Comment: A better solution for what? `01/01/2015` holds no timezone information, which is crucial to determine the actual date, including the proper time. So it needs to be added to your DateTime object. Furthermore, you need  the format string. The only thing I can think of is making `new DateTimeZone()` a constant...

Comment: The date must be entered in this format (dd/mm/yyyy) in the form but, in the database, it must be stored in a Date field for data manipulation. My solution is a better solution to have consistent date. If I enter "01/02/2015" (Paris time), I will not have "31/01/2015" (UTC) but "01/02/2015" (UTC). I thought my solution was a little bit too much in my controller but it's probably the better.

Answer (score -1):

```
   db.getCollection('my_collection').aggregate([
       { $project: { title: 1, date: { $add: [ "$date", 60*60000 ] } } }
   ])
```

Store date in iso format that is `ISODate("2015-01-31T23:00:00.000")` and query like mentioned above.

Comment: Data should be _persisted_ correctly, not modified to be correct during queries.